# ui-material rating don't click on value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

The method onChange for clicking on a star with the number value does not work. In my example it's 4. Why ? How can I change it ?
https://material-ui.com/components/rating/

[image]

```
   <Rating
      name="hover-tooltip"
      value={4}
      precision={0.5}
      IconContainerComponent={IconContainer}
      onChange={(event, newValue) => {
        console.log(444) // when click on star number four this method don't work
        // this.setState({value: newValue})
        // this.props.onRating(newValue);
      }}
      disabled={false}
    />
```

Comment: remove precision={0.5} or IconContainerComponent={IconContainer} and try again

Comment: try changing this `value={4}` to `value={this.state.value}`

Comment: I can't remove them, I need them, I also tried change it to this.state.value but result is same it's 4 and it don't work

Comment: and even i remvoe them it still don't work